# How do i acknowledge gnome 3 notifications using the keyboard?

Tags: linux, unix, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, cinnamon

The title says it. I have been looking for a mouseless method to acknowledge the spiffy gnome 3 notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature available right now (interaction via keyboard hotkeys). The best you can do is use notifyosdconfig and use functionality such as "close on click".

I presume it's possible to code support for keyboard hotkeys, but I haven't found any such patches around.